# Set class within iframe of another page

Tags: jquery, ajax, iframe

Page B contains an iframe whose src is page A.  Page A by default does not have a class.  I would like to add the class when rendered within iframe of page B.

Let me demonstrate...

Page A element (https:page_a.com).  Class 'activated' not set.

```
<li>
    <a href="#" class="" id="stay" alt="Stay">
        <i class="fa fa-bed"></i>
        <span class="">Stay</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Page B iframe (https:page_b.com). Class 'activated' set when rendered on this page.

```
<iframe src="https:page_a.com" id="stay" class="activated" seamless="seamless" scrolling="no"  width="100%" height="450px">
</iframe>
```

Such that when loaded on page b...

```
<li>
    <a href="#" class="activated" id="stay" alt="Stay">
        <i class="fa fa-bed"></i>
        <span class="">Stay</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Is this possible thru jquery?

Comment: Yes, as long as you can edit both pages

Comment: Thanks @zer00ne . Perhaps an example?

Comment: Just a couple of questions first 1. you can edit both pages? 2. Are both pages on the same domain?

Comment: Separate domains. Yes I have access to both.

Comment: Separate domains the Post Message should suffice. Is the active class totally necessary? Because given the nature of Post Message you can set behavior just by command. So if you want the parent page to be notified that the child page is loaded, Post Message could relay that when it happens.

Comment: What is Post Message? I dont necessarily need the class. I just need to emulate a click on this 'li' when loaded on the child page.

Comment: [PostMessage docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage). You are unable to use simpler approaches (all on same domain) due to *"same origin policy"*